# How to get NVMe queue proprieties

Tags: nvme

I have an SSD and I need to know how many queues there are, their lengths, how many adm queues, cores, etc.

I am running on a Linux machine and I have installed `nvme-cli` tool. The only thing I got was:

```
sudo nvme get-feature /dev/nvme0n1 --feature-id=7 -H
get-feature:0x7 (Number of Queues), Current value:0x1f001f
    Number of IO Completion Queues Allocated (NCQA): 32
    Number of IO Submission Queues Allocated (NSQA): 32
```

Comment: I think I may have seen this information in dmesg during boot.